# Unique values for azure b2c custom attribute

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am building registration journey using azure b2c user flows, I want to capture few data using custom attributes. The values captured via that custom attribute during registration should be unique per user.

The value of custom attribute can be autogenerated or can be captured from user.

Note: I don’t want to use custom policies.

I have found a workaround for this, by using pre-register API connector and querying azure b2c using graph api to validate the value of custom attribute.

I am looking for a smart way using user flow if azure b2c can validate the uniqueness of custom attribute for me during registration.

Answer (score 0):

That is the only way to do this.

Use an API connector at sign-up.

If you want to call more than one API and have some business smarts around this you have to call custom policies.

Comment: Thank you for confirming, can we show error response returned by api connector to user using user flows?

Comment: This works for custom policies - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile#returning-validation-error-message - never tried it with user flows